# include time from moment.js via ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, ejs

Creating a blog site, where time at which the user posted the blog appears, like this : [image]
Code : In app.js,

```
var moment = require("moment");
var now = moment();

  app.get("/blog", function(req,res) {
  console.log(moment().format("MMM Do YYY, h:mm:ss a"));
  Blogdemo.find({}).sort([['_id', -1]]).exec(function(err,allBlogs) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("blog", {blog : allBlogs, moment : now});
    }
  })
})
```

In landing.ejs,

```
<span><%= moment.format("MMM Do YYY, h:mm:ss a"); %></span> //to display time
```

The console.log works perfectly, but I'm unable to display the time on the landing page.

Comment: did you include moment in your head to get moment.js? Define "something is wrong"?

Comment: @lloyd I used "npm install" to install it. Like I said, the console.log is working fine, but the time in the span tag can't be displayed.

Comment: Any error messages? What is the output?

Comment: @RyanZim I somehow got it to work, it still needs some work though. I 'm having another 2 extremely important(not difficult) issues.They need the same skills your profile mentions(css,ejs,node..). Could you help me with them?

Comment: @eknoor4197 See if you can figure them out yourself. If you can't a Google doesn't help, ask a new question. Perhaps I'll end up answering it.

Comment: @RyanZim I've already asked one, but neither it has any answrs nor any sufficient number of ways : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681113/set-background-image-with-ejs-template
The 2nd question is regarding express middleware, I wanted to ask it here but I'm not getting my questions answered here so...